# In Jmeter, how to replace default ResultCollector class for my custom implementation?

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to save the http response to the output (jtl) file when I run jmeter using the following command lines:

`jmeter -n -t my-test.jmx -l my-output.jtl`

I found out that the parameter `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data` allows to save the http response data, but it only happens when `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml` for obvious reasons.

So, I decided to implement my own `ResultCollector` but I don't know how to configure jmeter to use mine instead of the default behavior.

Some clue?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a better idea either configure a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) to store whatever and wherever your want.

If none of existing Listeners is suitable for you it's better to [come up with your own Listener implementation by developing your own JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugin-development).

Substituting the [ResultCollector](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/ResultCollector.html) with a custom class is not something you can do via configuration without amending JMeter's source code in multiple locations (like get JMeter source, delete [ResultCollector.java](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/ResultCollector.java), try to compile, fix compilation errors by replacing it with your class, etc.), at least as of [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl)